# is there a smarter diff for SmartGit

Tags: diff, smartgit

Can SmartGit do something like git's `indent-heuristic`? This has been available since Git 2.11, so more than a year.

It is described here:

> we mentioned some improvements to the diff algorithm to make the
>   results easier to read (the --compaction-heuristic option). That
>   algorithm did not become the default because there were some corner
>   cases that it did not handle well. But after some very thorough
>   analysis, Git 2.11 has an improved algorithm that behaves similarly
>   but covers more cases and does not have any regressions. The new
>   option goes under the name --indent-heuristic (and
>   diff.indentHeuristic), and will likely become the default in a future
>   version of Git

Here is the [link to the Git announcement about this.](https://blog.github.com/2016-11-29-git-2-11-has-been-released/)

I am using SmartGit 17.0.2 (non-commercial).

Comment: Check SmartGit 18.1 RC, which comes with diff improvements -- especially give **Ignore [No|Leading|All] Whitespaces** options a try.